# What are the best fonts to use in a text heavy screen in smartphones?

Tags: mobile

I am designing app for a online service provider. Most of the screens are text heavy. So which fonts are better to use?

Answer (score 2):

Being a very legible font designed for user interfaces and with mobile device usage in mind, [Droid Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Droid+Sans) would not be an unreasonable font choice to go with.

A Google search (which I'm sure you've done already) will give you plenty of lists, but Ian Hex's article [What Should I Look For In a UI Typeface?](http://www.design-by-izo.com/2011/10/18/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-ui-typeface/)  on Design-by-IZO is definitely one of the better and more useful ones and coincidentally reaches the same conclusion I did above.

[image]

---

<sub>Note: Ariana Grande is not a font</sub>